# css and js files not found(server responded with a status of 404) while browsing application on iis7

Tags: javascript, css, iis

I published my solution on vs 2010. 
Examples of references to style sheets and js files(*first method*):

```
<link href="../../Content/CSS/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/ApplicationSecurity/AuthenticateUser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These work fine while debugging. But while browsing on *iis* 7 the resources fail to load. In my other applications I have used(*second method*):

```
<link href="~/Content/CSS/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and this works fine both during debug and browse on *iis*. 
The URL of the view page is:

```
http://localhost/LaunchLogin/
```

The error on console:

```
Failed to load http://localhost/Content/css/Login.css resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

It should search for the file in:

```
http://localhost/LaunchLogin/Content/css/Login.css
```

Can anyone explain how *iis* tries to access the resources? Also how can I configure *iis* or publish in such a way that the *first method* works on *iss* browse?

Comment: Do you have these files in your published folder?

Comment: Of course.. I checked

Comment: Allow MIME types for JS and CSS files extensions

Comment: Also put URL of page in question?

Comment: First make sure your URLs are alright, press `control + U` and try to click on your JS and CSS files paths, and make sure the path is alright, then look for the MIME types to allow from the IIS manager

Comment: The URL is working fine in debug but not in iis

Comment: MIME type already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `~` base path has no problem and the best(and as you said; work perfectly), but if you still need relative path try with these tags, I remove one directory up path.

```
<link href="../Content/CSS/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/ApplicationSecurity/AuthenticateUser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**BTW,**

if your URL is `http://localhost/LaunchLogin/` and your css file is in `http://localhost/LaunchLogin/Content/css/Login.css` then your code for linking css should be:

```
<link href="Content/CSS/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/ApplicationSecurity/AuthenticateUser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

**If you wish to do,** then the next best method is to use *absolute paths* in CSS and JS linking. You can use following trick to do so:

1. Create a public static class with one variable: `public String absRoot='http://localhost/LaunchLogin/';` and set it to whatever the root of your website.
2. Now link CSS and JS like following:

---

```
<link href="<%=StaticClassName.absRoot %>Content/CSS/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%=StaticClassName.absRoot %>Scripts/ApplicationSecurity/AuthenticateUser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3. After that whenever you need you can change `absRoot` value at one place only.

Comment: I do not want to change the URLs.. Is there any way I can configure the publish in such a way that the required path is taken in iis browse?

Comment: @MukundPradeep Its not IIS, when you are using relative URLs(../) then browser sent the request on one-level-up directory and **HERE** your page is at `/LaunchLogin/` and css-link is `../../Content/`, **NOW** your browser will send request at `/Content/`.(as there as only one possible directory-up-path). **|** and if you have doubt that why its working in debug-mode then may be there page is at `/LaunchLogin/sub-folder/another-dir/` **OR** your page as root level so `../../` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Now I understand the problem.. Thank you for the shining light xD